# Exception when creating XML file on c# with WriteStartElement()

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

So here is the code that throws the exception

```
    #region Header
            if (textBox2.Text != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    xmlTW.WriteStartElement("Header");
                    xmlTW.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine);
                    xmlTW.WriteString(textBox2.Text);
                    xmlTW.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine);
                    xmlTW.WriteEndElement();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            #endregion


            #region Body
            if (textBox3.Text != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    xmlTW.WriteStartElement("Rectangles");
                    xmlTW.WriteRaw(Environment.NewLine + textBox3.Text + Environment.NewLine);
                    xmlTW.WriteEndElement();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            #endregion
```

So, the problem is that the code will run smoothly only if one of the two textboxes is filled with data, if both of them contain text i get an invalid operation exception at WriteEndDocument();

I know it must be something simple, but i just can't figure it out :P .
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have this at the beginning of the document?

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Yeah i did, thanks for your reply anyway :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well-formed XML must have a *Single* root element. Following is well-formed XML:

```
<Header>
Some text
</Header>
```

It is well-formed because `Header` is root element there. However, following is not well-formed:

```
<Header>
Some text
</Header>
<Rectangles>
Some other text
</Rectangles>
```

To correct it, you got to put it in some root element.

```
<myRoot>
<Header>
Some text
</Header>
<Rectangles>
Some other text
</Rectangles>
</myRoot>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know i had to wrap everything in a generic container.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `XmlWriterSettings` ConformanceLevel to `Fragment`.

This will enable you keep the xml struct that you wanted without adding root element

```
var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlWriterSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
```

and create you xml write like this:

```
XmlWriter xmlTW = XmlWriter.Create("myFile.xml", xmlWriterSettings)
```

[This](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter) link can help you start working with XmlWriter

Comment: Oh i see , this is very helpful, both answers are accepted, but i already solved it using the above solution.Will keep in mind your solution as well,also thanks for the tutorial.I will upvote once i reach the rep required.
Thanks again.

Comment: This may probably resolve exception. However, I think its better practice to keep your XML well-formed.